# Is it possible to encode AVI video to MP4 using Azure function?

Tags: java, encoding, azure-functions, jave2

Since Azure Media Service is being retired next year, I was thinking to try different approach to encode a video to MP4 and this approach includes Azure Function. The flow would be like this

1. Get `BlobInputStream` by calling `blobClient.openInputStream()` on `BlobClient`.
2. Get `byte[]` from `BlobInputStream`.
3. Use some library to perform encoding like [JAVE2](https://github.com/a-schild/jave2) or `FFMPEG`.(This is where my confusion is how to do this).
4. Hopig above would result in `byte[]`, create `InputStream` from byte[].
5. Write encoded video to storage account container by calling `upload(InputStream data)` on `BlobClinet`.

In theory sounds simple but the problem I am running into here is JAVE2 and other similar libraries accepts `java.io.File` object for input and output but `azure-storage-blob` library does not exposes any api to get `File` object. Now option left is to open inputstream to get byte[] but then how to encode a byte array.

**Update**: Input file size is max 100MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this with Java azure function and [JAVE2](https://github.com/a-schild/jave2) library. I got the SAS Url of source file, then fed that to `MultimediaObject`

Sample Code:

```
private File encoded = null;

MultimediaObject multimediaObject = new MultimediaObject(new URL(blobSasUrl));

VideoAttributes video = new VideoAttributes();
video.setCodec(LIBX264_CODEC);
video.setFrameRate(FRAME_RATE);

EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
attrs.setOutputFormat(ENCODE_FORMAT);
attrs.setVideoAttributes(video);

Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
encoder.encode(multimediaObject, encoded, attrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The blob storage is not for files, but objects. You could use a stream to pass data, not any File using the BlobClient.

From the blob storage the objects needs to be dowloaded locally (not sure what local storage the functions have)

Another option is to mount Azure share as a filesystem to the functions runtime
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations

Yet - imho the serverless functions are intended to be quick with limited processing time, which the video encoding is not. So you may end up with timeouts and much higher cost than just running some compute (e. g. a container) or using Azure Batch with spot nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to encode AVI video to MP4 using an Azure Function. You can create an Azure Function that triggers on the event of a new AVI video being uploaded to a storage account, and then use a video processing library or tool (such as FFmpeg) within the function to perform the AVI to MP4 conversion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).